# Наведен ли курсор на элемент

Tags: jquery, javascript

Я не хочу привязывать событие и лишний раз грузить сайт, есть ли способ определить в нужный момент находится ли сейчас курсор на элементе с определенным id?

Answer (score 1):

вот так можно - (таймаут для демо)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var $test=$('#test')
  setInterval(function() {
    if ($test.is(':hover')) console.log('hovered'); else console.log('not hovered')
  },1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aw9Rc/

правда я не уверен что это везде будет работать и что это оптимальнее

```
document.on('focus','#test',function() {})
```